# Postgresql Retrieve / Find Primary Key Serial Autonumber field for Audit logs

Tags: postgresql, database-design, primary-key

I need to find the Primary Key field name in each of a number (approx 70) of tables to create audit logs. 
All the primary keys are type serial (auto incrementing integer) and all have the name in the format TablenameID eg so a table with the name "person" will have the serial primary key called "PersonID".  The only way I can find to do this is:

http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Retrieve_primary_key_columns

```
SELECT               
  pg_attribute.attname, 
  format_type(pg_attribute.atttypid, pg_attribute.atttypmod) 
FROM pg_index, pg_class, pg_attribute 
WHERE 
  pg_class.oid = 'person'::regclass AND
  indrelid = pg_class.oid AND
  pg_attribute.attrelid = pg_class.oid AND 
  pg_attribute.attnum = any(pg_index.indkey)
  AND indisprimary
```

the disadvantage is the extra time this will add to the creation of the audit logs, from explain (on an empty table)

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.01..54.92 rows=1 width=72)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..14.48 rows=1 width=31)
        ->  Seq Scan on pg_index  (cost=0.00..6.20 rows=1 width=31)
              Filter: (indisprimary AND (indrelid = 17606::oid))
        ->  Index Only Scan using pg_class_oid_index on pg_class  (cost=0.00..8.27 rows=1 width=4)
              Index Cond: (oid = 17606::oid)
  ->  Index Scan using pg_attribute_relid_attnum_index on pg_attribute  (cost=0.01..40.42 rows=2 width=78)
        Index Cond: ((attrelid = 17606::oid) AND (attnum = ANY ((pg_index.indkey)::smallint[])))
Time: 0.103s
```

Is there a better / faster way of doing this? The serial autonumber key name can be changed at this stage of the project.

Comment: Common approaches are to pass the name of the primary key column(s) into the trigger as arguments at `CREATE TRIGGER` time, or (undesirable IMO) to rely on a naming scheme. The trouble is that for perfection you need to handle the fact that the primary key column can change name or type at any time, even within a transaction, so you need to look it up each time unless you don't allow users to `ALTER TABLE`.

Comment: @CraigRinger Thanks.  I don`t want to rely on a naming scheme. The users are not allowed to ALTER TABLE. Does the trigger function need to have the name of the primary key or is there a way of setting this as a variable? Since all the Primary Key fields are serial I automatically get person_PersonID_seq which I want. Another option would be to give all the primary keys the same name eg id and then create the sequences separately?

Comment: How I handle this is I write a PL/PgSQL procedure that takes the target table name and schema as arguments, looks the primary key or other column of interest up from the system catalogs, and generates a `CREATE TRIGGER` statement that it executes to create a parameterized trigger. If you want to you could even `CREATE FUNCTION` a per-table customised trigger function. One example of how this can work is here: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus